# Conditional calculations with Pandas | Remaining supply of transaction sheet

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that lists the transactions of a product. It shows the value of each product and how many are included in the transaction.

```
# Input: Transaction Sheet

      Products     Single Value      Amount      Type         
0     Prod1          -112,20          15,00      Buy   
1     Prod1         -221,84           12,00      Sell  
2     Prod1          339,93           48,00      Buy
3     Prod1         -855,50           13,00      Buy
4     Prod1           68,40           90,00      Buy
5     Prod1           45,1            10,00      Sell
..    ....           .......       ........      ....
8     Prod1         1.179,10          12,00      Sell
9     Prod1         -355,52           15,00      Buy
10    Prod1          -23,23           18,00      Sell
11    Prod1         -3235,33         300,00      Sell
```

I want to get a single row at the end that expresses the current stock of the product. If there is no more product in stock, no dataframe should be created. But if there is stock, the remaining value and number of the product should be expressed there.

```
# Output: Remaining inventory and average purchase price


      Products     Average Value      Amount         
0     Prod1          -112,20          15,00
```

If I wasn't using pandas, I would simply iterate through the rows and add/subtract existing sets. If there is still stock at the end, I calculate the average value of all transactions before the last total sale.

I haven't found a viable way to solve this with pandas yet - it's quite new for me. Can anyone help me with how I can implement such calculations?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt to use the cumsum() function to get you your inventory on hand.  I haven't gotten this working with grouping products yet, so it may actually be a step in the wrong direction.  Nonetheless, it's here for discussion:

```
import pandas as pd


def get_change(amount, type): 
  if type  == 'Buy':  
    return amount
  else:  
    return -amount



df = pd.DataFrame( {
  'Products': ['Prod1'] * 10 , 
  'Single Value': ['-112.2',  '-221.84',  '339.93',  '-855.5',  '68.4',  '45.1',  '1.179.10',  '-355.52',  '-23.23',  '-3235.33'], 
  'Amount': [ 15,  12,  48,  13,  90,  10,  12,  15,  18,  300], 
  'Type': [ 'Buy',  'Sell',  'Buy',  'Buy',  'Buy',  'Sell',  'Sell',  'Buy',  'Sell',  'Sell']
} )

df['change'] = df.apply( lambda row : get_change( row['Amount'], row['Type'] ), axis = 1 )
df['onhand'] = df['change'].cumsum() 
print(df)
```

Yields:

```
  Products Single Value  Amount  Type  change  onhand
0    Prod1       -112.2      15   Buy      15      15
1    Prod1      -221.84      12  Sell     -12       3
2    Prod1       339.93      48   Buy      48      51
3    Prod1       -855.5      13   Buy      13      64
4    Prod1         68.4      90   Buy      90     154
5    Prod1         45.1      10  Sell     -10     144
6    Prod1     1.179.10      12  Sell     -12     132
7    Prod1      -355.52      15   Buy      15     147
8    Prod1       -23.23      18  Sell     -18     129
9    Prod1     -3235.33     300  Sell    -300    -171
```

That said, this only works for me when the product is the same (as it is in your data example).  Experimentation with `groupby('Products')` has not yielded the results I am looking for in the onhand column.  Due to this limited progress, I'll submit this as an approach - perhaps not a viable one.

Comment: Thank you for your help, @Mark That brought me one step closer. I am able to proceed with the rest of the calculation. I just get a warning becuase of using row instead of .loc. I'm not sure how to fix that. 

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:120: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead